# how to recover corrupted php file

Tags: php, file, recover

[Click here to see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6LqX.png)

help me guys, I created this file 4years ago, but now I am getting an error, I think this file is corrupt.
I open this file for many software like dreamweaver, notepad++, notepad, WordPad, MSOffice, HostGator server, onedrive, google drive. but none open this file.
I attach screenshot please help me.

Comment: change encoding when opening the file what editor you using?

Answer (score -1):

Open the PHP file with **Notepad++**.

From the **Encoding** menu, select **Convert to UTF-8 without BOM**, save the file, replace the old file with this new file.

Comment: I try this but the only file size is an increase, before convert 18kb after convert 28.9kb, please help me. see screenshot I capture after convert https://ibb.co/dESDaa

Comment: please check <script https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1c72d1ba5b91ac480e3c9ea78b7c97a9

Comment: I thought you said it was a PHP file, but that on link is a js file? Why is it so?

Comment: PHP and js code in this file  https://gist.github.com/mrsiddharthshankar/793f3ad30355140d5a11b202260e41a6